# Updating/deleting rows from tables (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

Im trying (without success) to update/delete rows from a table.

Note: my database name is "desafio" and table "materias" contains: (id, carrera_id (is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "carreras") nombre, descripcion, carga_horaria)

I got this 2 errors when clicking buttons "edit" & "delete" respectively:

[I cannot upload the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKNYn.png)

[I cannot upload the image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Q9X.png)

Here is the index file:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    foreach($records as $record) {

        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$record->id."</td>
                  <td>".$record->carrera."</td>
                  <td>".$record->nombre."</td>
                  <td>".$record->descripcion."</td>
                  <td>".$record->carga_horaria."</td>
                  <td align='center'>
                    <a href='".site_url('Home/edit')."/$record->id'> 
                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                    <a href='".site_url('Home/delete')."/$record->id'> 
                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>

              </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Here is the controller file (with functions edit,saveupdate and delete)

```
        public function edit($id){

        $data['record']=$this->Crudmodel->get_row_id($id);
        $this->load->view('editar', $data);

    }

    public function saveupdate(){

            $txtcarr=$this->input->post("txtcarr");
            $txtmat=$this->input->post("txtmat");
            $txtdesc=$this->input->post("txtdesc");
            $txtcarga=$this->input->post("txtcarga");

        $this->Crudmodel->save($txtcarr,$txtmat,$txtdesc,$txtcarga);

        redirect('Home/index');

    }

    public function delete($id){

        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('desafio');

        redirect('Home/index');

    }
```

The crudmodel (with the function get_row_id)

```
        public function get_row_id($id){

      $this->db->where('id',$id);
      $query=$this->db->get('id');
      return $query->row();

    }
```

And the file "editar" which allows me to correct the information written:

```
    </head>
```

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


    <h2 align="center">UPDATE SUBJECTS</h2>
    <form method="post" action='<?php echo site_url('Home/saveupdate'); ?>'>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <select name="txtcarr">
                <?php foreach($carreras as $item):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->nombre;?></option>
                 <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Materia : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtmat" value="<?php echo $record->nombre ?>"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Descripcion : </td>
        <td><textarea name="txtdesc" value="<?php echo $record->descripcion ?>"></textarea></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Carga horaria : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtcarga"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="save"/></td>

    </tr>


        <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">



        </table>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Do not understand what is going on :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `delete` function shouldn't you use the table name?

```
$this->db->delete('materias');
```

Comment: Yeah mate, you're right!. But wha tabout the update function?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, sorry!

Comment: Oh, it does not matter dude, thank you for helping me :)

Comment: You are welcome! I would suggest that you did not accept the answer though and just upvote it instead. This way there might be others who could give a hand and perhaps help you resolve the other issue.